# changing value for a div changes the values for all the divs in a loop in a ngfor angular 8

Tags: angular, data-binding, angular8, ngfor

I have a scenario, where by default, the screen shows an add button. On click of the add button, a dropdown appears -replacing the add button (I am using an ngIf Condition there).

There is a list of such Add Buttons, which is under an *ngFor condition.

component.html

```
 <li class="" *ngFor="let data of arr.count">
                    <a href="javascript: void(0);">
                      
                      <div class="media" *ngIf="arr.userId != EditId" >
                        <div class="media-body overflow-hidden">
                          <h5 class="text-truncate font-size-14 mb-1">
                            Add User
                          </h5>
                 
                        </div>
                        <div
                          class="font-size-21 add-button"
                          (click)="editUser(arr.userId)"
                        >
                          <i class="bx bx-plus-circle"></i>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="" *ngIf="arr.userId == EditId">
                        <div class="form-group mb-4">
                          <ng-select
                            [items]="selectValue"
                            bindLabel="value"
                            bindValue="metaId"
                            [(ngModel)]="userModel.user"
                            (ngModelChange)="
                              hideUser(
                                arr.userId,
                                userModel.user
                              )
                            "
                          ></ng-select>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </a>
                  </li>
```

component.ts

```
EditId: any = ''
....
...
...
ngOnInit(){
}
..
..
editUser(val: any) {
    this.EditId = val
    this.loadUserList()
  }

  hideUser(id, userId) {
    this.EditId = ''
  }
```

However, on clicking an add button, I want only that particular row to be impacted. But I see that all the rows have the button replaced with dropdowns.

What am I missing?

I have updated my code. But now, the first add user is always as a dropdown. The rest works.
**updated code:**

```
 <li class="" *ngFor="let data of arr.count">
                        <a href="javascript: void(0);">
                          
                          <div class="media" *ngIf="data.userId != EditId" >
                            <div class="media-body overflow-hidden">
                              <h5 class="text-truncate font-size-14 mb-1">
                                Add User
                              </h5>
                     
                            </div>
                            <div
                              class="font-size-21 add-button"
                              (click)="editUser(data.userId)"
                            >
                              <i class="bx bx-plus-circle"></i>
                            </div>
                          </div>

                          <div class="" *ngIf="data.userId == EditId">
                            <div class="form-group mb-4">
                              <ng-select
                                [items]="selectValue"
                                bindLabel="value"
                                bindValue="metaId"
                                [(ngModel)]="userModel.user"
                                (ngModelChange)="
                                  hideUser(
                                    arr.userId,
                                    userModel.user
                                  )
                                "
                              ></ng-select>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </a>
                      </li>
```

Comment: I must suppose you has an array of users, so you need iterate over `*ngFor="let userModel of arr"`. Then you can use the variable "userModel" inside the divs, e.g.`[(ngModel)]="userModel.user"`, `*ngIf="userModel.userId==EditId` , `(click)="editUser(userModel.userId)"` ... Really I don't know about your arr.count

Comment: So I have the array of users under arr.count. It's more of a nested array.

Comment: then use **data**, NOT **arr**

Comment: I have updated my code. But now, the first `add user` is always as a dropdown. The rest works.

Comment: @Eliseo.. thanks it works now!!! the arr.count['id'] was having 0 as the first id, hence the previous error.